# Can eclipse be automated to automatically give your apk a different name when debugging?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'd like to test my app on my phone, but obviously the app signed with the debug cert conflicts with the app published on the market.

I'm trying to locate a problem that I suspect is associated with proguard so I'd like to have both scenarios on my phone to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to know if proguard works , you can de-obfuscate the apk's code and see if it's readable .

you can also look at the output proguard folder and see the things that it has done.

alternatively , you can use reflection on a pure class (one that doesn't have anything to do with android) with strings , to see if proguard has touched it or not . if it did , you will get an exception since the app couldn't find it (since proguard changed its name) , and the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You can Manually Rename your apk file name.And then install it so that it will not remove your previous installation